# Uncaught Error: Class "App\Controller\Wallet"

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

this is my project Structure

[image]

and this is my hook.php
[image]

I got this error when I used Wallet Class in Hook.php!

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "App\Controller\Wallet" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tel\hook.php:5
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tel\hook.php on line 5

[image]

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi         Yes, I didn't get any results

Comment: Try again after running the above command

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Nothing happened

Comment: Do you not load composer's `autoload.php`? And don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to include vendor/autoload.php in your hook.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```